# Collection of all functions which takes values into $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let
$A$
be the collection of all functions :

$$f_i:D\to\mathbb R^3$$

Show that $A$ is a vector space?

My approach :

So $A$ is a "thing" which outputs every value of $\mathbb R^3$ and uses every element of $D$. To be a vector space we have definition

$(A,+)$ should be an abelian group. And there exists a scalar $k$ such that $kx$ is a member of $A$ if $x$ is a member of $A$.

But I can't think of a way how to prove this since A is a collection of Functions :

Let's say $A$ is a set of functions $f_i$ if you add for instance $f_x+f_y$ would be a member of $A$. Inverses of functions exist too. Identity function exists. Scalar multiplication stays in $A$.

A seems like a vector space from this point of view. Am i thinking right? Am i on a right path? And btw what is the purpose of giving out $\mathbb R^3$ here, wouldn't this work out if the codomain was some random set $S$?

Comment: Try to define addition where your codomain is $\{7,12\}$.

Comment: What does the subscript $i$ refer to? $\qquad$

Comment: i,x,y are elements of real numbers.

Comment: A more general statement is true: If $D$ is any set and $V$ is a vector space, then the set of functions $D \to V$ is a vector space.

Answer (score 1):

So $A$ is the set $A=\{f:  \ \ \ f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3\}$ equipped with two operations "$  +$" and "$\cdot$" defined as follows:

-If $f, g\in A$, then $f+g$ is the function defined as $(f+g)(d)=f(d)+g(d),$ for every $d\in D$.

-If $f\in A$ and $\lambda \in\mathbb{R}$, then $\lambda f$ is the function defined as $(\lambda f)(d)=\lambda f(d)$, for every $d\in D$.

It's worth to mention here that in order to define the operations on $A$, we relied heavily on the fact that the expressions $f(d)+g(d)$ and $\lambda f(d)$ make sense. In other words, we used the fact that $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a vector space. So you can't use any random set as a codomain, you need to use a vector space (any vector space will do and the proof is exactly the same as in the case of $\mathbb{R}^3$).

Now, all you need to show is that $(A, +, \cdot)$ is a vector space. The bad news is that you have to show the eight properties of the definition of a vector space. The good news is that all of them are easily verified.

I'll explicitly write down one of them just to demonstrate you the reasoning.

-*Existence of identity element:* We need to find an $f_0\in A$ such that $f+f_0=f$, for every $f\in A$. Lets take as $f_0$ the function which satisfies $f_0(d)=0$, for every $d \in D$. Then for every $f\in A$, $(f+f_0)(d)=f(d)+f_0(d)=f(d)+0=f(d)$, for every $d\in D$. So $f+f_0=f$.

The rest of the properties are shown in a similar fashion.